# How to join each element of a list in KStream (Kafka Streams)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

For example I have a KStream of shopping carts and each shopping cart has a List of product id's. Additionally there is a KStream with products. How do I join them together?

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    List<ProductKey> productKeys;
}

public class Product {
    ProductKey key;
    String name;
}

public class ProductKey {
    String id;
}

KStream<String, ShoppingCart> shoppingCartKStream;
KStream<ProductKey, Product> productKStream;
```

My desired result would look like this

```
KStream<String, ShoppingCartWithProducts> joinedStream;
public class ShoppingCartWithProducts {
    List<Product> products;
}
```

Is there an easy way to archive this?

EDIT:
I know there is a way but I find it too complicated. To put it simply:

1. I need to flatMap the shoppingCart-KStream
2. Then I can join the result with the product-KStream
3. Group and aggregate the intermediate result
4. And finally join back with shoppingCart-KStream

   ```
   KStream<String, ProductKey> productKeyStream = shoppingCartKStream
           .flatMap((key, shoppingCart) -> shoppingCart.productKeys.stream()
                   .map(productKey -> KeyValue.pair(key, productKey))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList())
           );

   KTable<String, Product> productStreamWithShoppingCartKey = productKeyStream.toTable()
           .join(
                   productKStream.toTable(),
                   productKey -> productKey,
                   (productKey, product) -> product
           );

   KTable<String, ArrayList<Product>> productListStream = productStreamWithShoppingCartKey
           .groupBy(KeyValue::pair)
           .aggregate(
                   (Initializer<ArrayList<Product>>) ArrayList::new,
                   (key, value, aggregate) -> addProductToList(aggregate, value),
                   (key, value, aggregate) -> removeProductFromList(aggregate, value)
           );

   KStream<String, ShoppingCartWithProducts> shoppingCartWithProductsKStream = shoppingCartKStream.join(
           productListStream,
           (shoppingCart, productList) -> new ShoppingCartWithProducts(productList)
   );
   ```

And of course it's very simplified, I also need to handle tombstone and so on.

Answer (score 0):

After you define you `StreamsBuilder` that is the entry point to the Streams DSL.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
```

you can do a join of a 5 minutes window using `JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5))`. You have to have the keys of both stream using the same type otherwise `kafka-stream` cannot compare keys of different types. It is like a database join. So, I am using `String` for `ShoppingCart` and `Product`. Then the `.join(...` operator matches events of the same key and you can build your new event `ShoppingCartWithProducts`.

```
KStream<String, ShoppingCart> shoppingCartKStream = ...;
KStream<String, Product> productKStream = ...;

shoppingCartKStream.join(productKStream,
    (shop, prod) -> {
        log.info("ShoppingCart: {} with Product: {}", shop, prod);

        ShoppingCartWithProducts shoppingCartWithProducts = new ShoppingCartWithProducts();
        shoppingCartWithProducts.setShoppingCart(shop);
        shoppingCartWithProducts.setProduct(prod);
        return shoppingCartWithProducts;
    },
    JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)),
    StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(),
        new JsonSerde<>(ShoppingCart.class),
        new JsonSerde<>(Product.class)))
   .foreach((k, v) -> log.info("ShoppingCartWithProducts ID: {}, value: {}", k, v));
```

you can find more detailed information [here](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining).

Comment: Hi @Felipe, thanks for you answer. Maybe I'm missing something but in your solution ShoppingCartWithProducts would not have a list of products anymore but instead just one product? I edited my question with a simplified solution, but i find it to complicated. Maybe you can have a look

Comment: If you want a list of products inside the car-shop I would do an aggregation after the join. Take a look at this example of aggregation: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-aggregate